# SQL Server Table Partition Data Type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, partitioning, sqldatatypes, partition

I have a table with over 70 million rows which I want to partition using the date/time column, however the date/time column has varchar datatype instead of date.

What is the best way of converting the datatype dynamically to be able to use the column as a partition range ?

Thanks

Comment: Create a new table with the proper column types and partitioning.  Insert into the new table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , thank you for the promote response. It is not possible to move the data to a new table as this is application database and the format is vendor specific which I won't be able to modify. I was hoping if there is any way I can dynamically CAST or CONVERT the datatype to date/time during the partitioning process.

Comment: Well...you want to partition by a date but you don't have a date. You have varchar data which is not a date.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a new PERSISTED COMPUTED column and then create partition on the computed field. 
The computed column should be type of date and it is simply conversion of your varchar column.

I have done this before as experiment and it works.